# Search Through Matrix Field

Tags: matrix, craft3, search

Trying to search through a Matrix field, currently I am using conditionals to accomplish this, but if it's faster would like to limit the results to only what I need.

```
{% for row in entry.matrixField.search(matrixChild1:"mykeyword") %}

{% set getResults = row.matrixChild1.one.slug %}

{% endfor %}
```

I could not find much on this, I know a search() parametered can be used in Matrix but after all my trying still nothing.  Hopefully it's possible?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/searching.html#templating) there are so many examples how to search here at stack exchange and it's well explained in the docs. I posted the same answer multiple times within the last days

```
entry.matrixField.search("mykeyword").all()
```

As I already said a few times too "looping through queries is still deprecated". Please fetch your results with `.all()` or `.one()`. There is no reason to fill your logs with deprecated warnings - you won't have any benefits

Comment: My apologies, I did not seem to get it and I looked through the docs, thankfully good peeps like you are here to help out.  I spend a ton of time trying to get the answer before I ever post it on here.

Comment: Were you able to make it work now?

Comment: Sort of.  What I really need and would be epic is to get the matching done in the craft.entries tag.  I am 90% finished with my project and being so close I am so far away.  The solution you provided elsewhere I did not realize did not work as I expected.

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('flightcompany').relatedTo('and',
    { targetElement: models, field: 'partsModels.model' },
    { targetElement: parts, field: 'partsModels.part' }
) %}

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26107/combining-multiple-relation/26108#26108

Comment: What do you mean by `craft.entries` tag? `craft.entries` returns nearly the same type of object like `entry.matrixField` you can use the same syntax and the same parameters since both are `ElementQueries`. Maybe you should learn to provide proper feedback. My query will return all elements that contains `mykeyword`

Comment: Meaning the order in which I call the tags.  I have 80,000+ records, so looping through each entry and each entry has 10+ matrix records, in those records is 1 table 2 category fields. The table field can have 10-20 records each as text.  So it's pulling in the records from my main records in entries which there are 600+ of those.  So I am having to grab the main record and loop through each looking for specific records and writing conditionals to get only records meeting those conditions.

Comment: Then you should apply the correct filters for your entries instead of looping through them. But that was not your question

Comment: Well I guess I need that then, I don't know, I am at your mercy Robin :) . Can you show me what the correct filter would be...please.